# Saving boards in a file

Tags: python

I would love to have literary batch records on my computer, unfortunately this is not an option. I decided to write a program that records the layout of the letters on the board and the available letters on each line in a text file. My idea is to get it out of html with python, maybe with selenium. I know Python pretty well, but I can't say that about working with pages. Need an idea how to do it in the most efficient way (ie how to extract this data from an html page into an array or a list). The website is https://www.kurnik.pl/literaki.
I tried static methods, but it turned out to be a completely wrong approach and nothing came of it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the algorithms and logic to convert the page into a list, I may have a solution. Try making a csv file (comma separated values), which makes a table sort-of layout that can also be converted back to an array with ease. E.g.

```
with open('board.csv', 'w') as f:
  f.write(board data here)
  f.close()
```

Comment: The thing is, it needs an efficient algorithm to extract this data from raw html.

Comment: Then, my friend, you need to put in some code for people to devise an algorithm